# Logging in just returns me to the login prompt - sddm authorization file issue

Tags: fedora, kde, login, sddm

I just upgraded to Fedora 32, running KDE. By default it seems SDDM is the login greeter. When I log in the screen flickers and I am immediately returned to the greeter login prompt. Switching to a virtual terminal shows the following problem:

```
$ grep '(EE)' /var/log/Xorg.0.log
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   382.311] (EE) Failed to load module "nv" (module does not exist, 0)
[   496.956] (EE) Failed to open authorization file "/var/run/sddm/{abc45b8d-5b0d-479c-b259-97c2423927d1}": No such file or directory
```

The authorization file is the problem and I'm not the first (but can't find a solution):

- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/sddm-fails-to-open-authorization-file/84711/12
- https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/sddm-error-relating-to-authorization-file-how-to-troubleshoot/3916/3

I can `startx` from a terminal just fine. I tried creating another user with a new home directory and can also login just fine there. I tried copying `.config` and `.local` from the new home directory but still can't login to my user. What else should I be looking for in my home? Could this be an selinux issue?

---

As a workaround, I can just use another greeter.

```
sudo systemctl disable sddm.service
sudo dnf install kdm
sudo systemctl enable --now kdm.service
```

---

Update: even after disabling the sddm service I caught this popup on kde login "SELinux is preventing sddm-helper from write access on the directory /home/jozxyqk.". Maybe this was related.